# OpenLDAP Group: How to create a group object with both member and memberUid attributes?

Tags: openldap, schema

I've just installed and configured OpenLDAP 2.4 in CentOS 8 and I'm now creating Groups and it's members for future use.

One of these future use will be LDAP+PAM integration, which is why I want my Groups to have the memberUid attribute in the posixGroup objectClass, which is defined in nis.schema file that's shipped with OpenLDAP:

```
objectclass ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.2 NAME 'posixGroup'
    DESC 'Abstraction of a group of accounts'
    SUP top STRUCTURAL
    MUST ( cn $ gidNumber )
    MAY ( userPassword $ memberUid $ description ) )
```

But also I'd would like to use the member attribute from the groupOfNames objectClass, which is defined in core.schema:

```
objectclass ( 2.5.6.9 NAME 'groupOfNames'
    DESC 'RFC2256: a group of names (DNs)'
    SUP top STRUCTURAL
    MUST ( member $ cn )
    MAY ( businessCategory $ seeAlso $ owner $ ou $ o $ description ) )
```

But if I try to use both of theses objectClasses, I get a LDAP_OBJECT_CLASS_VIOLATION, since both of them are STRUCTURAL (in fact, and I believe that no so long ago posixGroup was AUXILIARY).

How can I use both of theses objectClasses without changing their original specification?

Is there an alternative, can I use "member" attribute or some objectClass other than posixGroup to integrate LDAP with PAM? Or is there another objectClass that's AUXILIARY and has "member" attribute?

The member attribute is very important for my future needs, but I was only going to use posixGroup for PAM integration.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the schema defined in [RFC2703bis](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-howard-rfc2307bis-02) as opposed to RFC2703 aka nis.schema.

Below is a wide ldif that should be suitable for adding with `ldapadd`, though I do worry that you're still using slapd.conf rather than slapd-config. (There may be a few modifications to allow substring matches not included in RFC2703bis on thing like automountkey because I'm lazy and like both substring matching and pulling from live configs).

---

```
dn: cn=rfc2307bis,cn=schema,cn=config
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: rfc2307bis
olcAttributeTypes: {0}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.2 NAME 'gecos' DESC 'The GECOS field; the common name' EQUALITY caseIgnoreIA5Match SUBSTR caseIgnoreIA5SubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {1}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.3 NAME 'homeDirectory' DESC 'The absolute path to the home directory' EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {2}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.4 NAME 'loginShell' DESC 'The path to the login shell' EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {3}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.5 NAME 'shadowLastChange' EQUALITY integerMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {4}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.6 NAME 'shadowMin' EQUALITY integerMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {5}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.7 NAME 'shadowMax' EQUALITY integerMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {6}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.8 NAME 'shadowWarning' EQUALITY integerMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {7}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.9 NAME 'shadowInactive' EQUALITY integerMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {8}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.10 NAME 'shadowExpire' EQUALITY integerMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {9}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.11 NAME 'shadowFlag' EQUALITY integerMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {10}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.12 NAME 'memberUid' EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 )
olcAttributeTypes: {11}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.13 NAME 'memberNisNetgroup' EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match SUBSTR caseExactIA5SubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 )
olcAttributeTypes: {12}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.14 NAME 'nisNetgroupTriple' DESC 'Netgroup triple' EQUALITY caseIgnoreIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 )
olcAttributeTypes: {13}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.15 NAME 'ipServicePort' DESC 'Service port number' EQUALITY integerMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {14}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.16 NAME 'ipServiceProtocol' DESC 'Service protocol name' SUP name )
olcAttributeTypes: {15}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.17 NAME 'ipProtocolNumber' DESC 'IP protocol number' EQUALITY integerMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {16}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.18 NAME 'oncRpcNumber' DESC 'ONC RPC number' EQUALITY integerMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {17}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.19 NAME 'ipHostNumber' DESC 'IPv4 addresses as a dotted decimal omitting leading zeros or IPv6 addresses as defined in RFC2373' SUP name )
olcAttributeTypes: {18}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.20 NAME 'ipNetworkNumber' DESC 'IP network as a dotted decimal, eg. 192.168, omitting leading zeros' SUP name SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {19}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.21 NAME 'ipNetmaskNumber' DESC 'IP netmask as a dotted decimal, eg. 255.255.255.0, omitting leading zeros' EQUALITY caseIgnoreIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {20}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.22 NAME 'macAddress' DESC 'MAC address in maximal, colon separated hex notation, eg. 00:00:92:90:ee:e2' EQUALITY caseIgnoreIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 )
olcAttributeTypes: {21}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.23 NAME 'bootParameter' DESC 'rpc.bootparamd parameter' EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 )
olcAttributeTypes: {22}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.24 NAME 'bootFile' DESC 'Boot image name' EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 )
olcAttributeTypes: {23}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.26 NAME 'nisMapName' DESC 'Name of a A generic NIS map' SUP name )
olcAttributeTypes: {24}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.27 NAME 'nisMapEntry' DESC 'A generic NIS entry' EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match SUBSTR caseExactIA5SubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {25}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.28 NAME 'nisPublicKey' DESC 'NIS public key' EQUALITY octetStringMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.40 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {26}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.29 NAME 'nisSecretKey' DESC 'NIS secret key' EQUALITY octetStringMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.40 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {27}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.30 NAME 'nisDomain' DESC 'NIS domain' EQUALITY caseIgnoreIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 )
olcAttributeTypes: {28}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.31 NAME 'automountMapName' DESC 'automount Map Name' EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match SUBSTR caseExactIA5SubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {29}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.32 NAME 'automountKey' DESC 'Automount Key value' EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match SUBSTR caseExactIA5SubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {30}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.33 NAME 'automountInformation' DESC 'Automount information' EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match SUBSTR caseExactIA5SubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcObjectClasses: {0}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.0 NAME 'posixAccount' DESC 'Abstraction of an account with POSIX attributes' SUP top AUXILIARY MUST ( cn $ uid $ uidNumber $ gidNumber $ homeDirectory ) MAY ( userPassword $ loginShell $ gecos $ description ) )
olcObjectClasses: {1}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.1 NAME 'shadowAccount' DESC 'Additional attributes for shadow passwords' SUP top AUXILIARY MUST uid MAY ( userPassword $ description $ shadowLastChange $ shadowMin $ shadowMax $ shadowWarning $ shadowInactive $ shadowExpire $ shadowFlag ) )
olcObjectClasses: {2}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.2 NAME 'posixGroup' DESC 'Abstraction of a group of accounts' SUP top AUXILIARY MUST gidNumber MAY ( userPassword $ memberUid $ description ) )
olcObjectClasses: {3}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.3 NAME 'ipService' DESC 'Abstraction an Internet Protocol service. Maps an IP port and protocol (such as tcp or udp) to one or more names; the distinguished value of the cn attribute denotes the services canonical name' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST ( cn $ ipServicePort $ ipServiceProtocol ) MAY description )
olcObjectClasses: {4}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.4 NAME 'ipProtocol' DESC 'Abstraction of an IP protocol. Maps a protocol number to one or more names. The distinguished value of the cn attribute denotes the protocols canonical name' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST ( cn $ ipProtocolNumber ) MAY description )
olcObjectClasses: {5}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.5 NAME 'oncRpc' DESC 'Abstraction of an Open Network Computing (ONC) [RFC1057] Remote Procedure Call (RPC) binding. This class maps an ONC RPC number to a name. The distinguished value of the cn attribute denotes the RPC services canonical name' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST ( cn $ oncRpcNumber ) MAY description )
olcObjectClasses: {6}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.6 NAME 'ipHost' DESC 'Abstraction of a host, an IP device. The distinguished value of the cn attribute denotes the hosts canonical name. Device SHOULD be used as a structural class' SUP top AUXILIARY MUST ( cn $ ipHostNumber ) MAY ( userPassword $ l $ description $ manager ) )
olcObjectClasses: {7}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.7 NAME 'ipNetwork' DESC 'Abstraction of a network. The distinguished value of the cn attribute denotes the networks canonical name' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST ipNetworkNumber MAY ( cn $ ipNetmaskNumber $ l $ description $ manager ) )
olcObjectClasses: {8}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.8 NAME 'nisNetgroup' DESC 'Abstraction of a netgroup. May refer to other netgroups' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST cn MAY ( nisNetgroupTriple $ memberNisNetgroup $ description ) )
olcObjectClasses: {9}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.9 NAME 'nisMap' DESC 'A generic abstraction of a NIS map' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST nisMapName MAY description )
olcObjectClasses: {10}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.10 NAME 'nisObject' DESC 'An entry in a NIS map' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST ( cn $ nisMapEntry $ nisMapName ) MAY description )
olcObjectClasses: {11}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.11 NAME 'ieee802Device' DESC 'A device with a MAC address; device SHOULD be used as a structural class' SUP top AUXILIARY MAY macAddress )
olcObjectClasses: {12}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.12 NAME 'bootableDevice' DESC 'A device with boot parameters; device SHOULD be used as a structural class' SUP top AUXILIARY MAY ( bootFile $ bootParameter ) )
olcObjectClasses: {13}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.14 NAME 'nisKeyObject' DESC 'An object with a public and secret key' SUP top AUXILIARY MUST ( cn $ nisPublicKey $ nisSecretKey ) MAY ( uidNumber $ description ) )
olcObjectClasses: {14}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.15 NAME 'nisDomainObject' DESC 'Associates a NIS domain with a naming context' SUP top AUXILIARY MUST nisDomain )
olcObjectClasses: {15}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.16 NAME 'automountMap' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST automountMapName MAY description )
olcObjectClasses: {16}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.17 NAME 'automount' DESC 'Automount information' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST ( automountKey $ automountInformation ) MAY description )
olcObjectClasses: {17}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.5322.13.1.1 NAME 'namedObject' SUP top STRUCTURAL MAY cn )
```

Comment: Thanks, and I'm not using slapd, I'm using cn=config, I just thought that posting the .schema version of the posixAccount objectClass would be clearer.

Is RFC2703bis older or newer then RFC2703bis (aka nis)? Is there an official place where I can get this ldiff?

Not that I do not trust you, I just wonder about future updates.

Comment: The first bis draft was published in 2002 about 4 and a half years after RFC2703 was published. To my knowledge it has never been formally adopted. The latest draft, linked in the answer is from 2009 and also contains a .schema version of the ldif above.